# .Net wrapper for HighStock

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I need to embed HighStock charts in an ASP.Net MVC application.

I found a few .Net wrappers for [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) (e.g [DotNet.HighCharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/)), but none of them seem to support [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock).

Is there any .Net wrapper for HighStock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any .Net wrapper that supports HighStock so far.

I finally ended up with an **unobtrusive javascript** approach: chart data generated on server side is embedded in the DOM (with "data-" attributes) and I have a pure javascript file that retrieves this data and builds the chart.

Comment: I'm using jQuery to handle events from DOM clicks and make GET requests to .Net in a RESTful fashion - .Net receives the query strings, grabs the data from stored procedures and bundles it back as a JSON object to configure the main highstock options.  Can you post an example of your `data-` attributes solution? It sounds interesting...